# AppCompat Issues in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, gradle, android-appcompat

I am having problems compiling my application to use on my phone. 
In my app file, I have:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
```

I had to fix something with the appcompat, and that seemed to do it, but whenever I compile my app, a huge file named `v21\values-v21.xml` appears and I'm left with a huge list of error messages.

I tried to just delete it, but it comes back whenever I sync the gradle or compile my app for my phone.

I've attached a file because the list of errors is just way too long to copy and paste. Here's a few images.[Here's a pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bf5gR.jpg)

Comment: Post your build.gradle